# Changing foreground color for players in a C# list

Tags: c#, list, colors

I am studying a course in programming (C#). Right now I am doing a task where I will create a version of a Dart 301 game.

I'm basically done with the game but would like to change the text color depending on which player is playing. This is not really necessary, it is not listed as something you should do but after I got the idea in my head I can not let go either lol. I really just want to know how to, been stuck now trying out different solutions.

When the game starts, you have to choose how many players to play. If it's 1 player, it plays against the computer, which I then solved to add the change in foreground color inside my foreach loop - for example:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
```

But when there is more than one player in the game I'm stuck.

Ideally I'd like to assign a color to each player joining the game. The player gets added through a AddPlayer method that I've created and then gets stored in a list of players in the Game class. There is also a Player class which holds a list of turns for each player.

What I've tried so far is

1. Creating a method for a random color (which is not ideal cause I'd like each player to get assigned a specific color):

```
private static ConsoleColor GetRandomColor()
{
    Random randomColor = new Random();
    var consoleColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor));
    return (ConsoleColor)consoleColors.GetValue(randomColor.Next(consoleColors.Length));
}
```

2. In the foreach loop then changing the color for each player in the list

```
    foreach (var player in ListOfPlayers)
    {
        for (int i =0; i <= ListOfPlayers.Count -1; i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomColor(); 
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t{0} it's your turn! What numbers did your arrows hit? " +
                          "\n\tREMEMBER: Each turn includes three throws with a possible score of 1-20 for each arrow. \n", player);
        arrowOne = GetPlayerThrow();
        arrowTwo = GetPlayerThrow();
        arrowThree = GetPlayerThrow();
        player.AddTurn(arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree);
        totalScore = player.CalculatePoints();
    }
```

3. I've also tried different types of if and foreach

**Hope my explanation did not get too messy. I would prefer to assign a color to a specific player in the list.**

Ex:

```
private List <Player> ListOfPlayers = new List <Player> ();
```

List item 0 If this player exists, the text will appear in DarkYellow.

List item 1 If this player exists, the text will appear in DarkCyan.

List item 2 If this player exists, the text will appear in DarkMagneta.

List item 3 If this player exists, the text will appear in DarkGreen.

Here's a picture of what I've done when the game is computer vs player:
When the computer is playing the text is red but when it's the players turn it is blue:
[image: When the computer is playing the text is red but when it's the players turn it is blue]

Comment: Create a `ConsoleColor` array and fill it with the desired colors. Then as players are added, assign them the next color from the array. You can use the player's index in the `ListOfPlayers` list to pick the color.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with the number of desired players and assign to each the desired color with a `switch`. Then start the game. An example below.

```
public class Game {
  private List<Player> ListOfPlayers = new List<Player>();
  public Game(int nbplayers) {
     InitPlayers(nbplayers);
  }
  public void InitPlayers(int nbplayers) {
     for(int i=0; i < nbplayers; i++) {
        var player = new Player();
        switch(i) {
           case 0: { player.Color = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow; break;}
           case 1: { player.Color = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan; break;}
           case 2: { player.Color = ConsoleColor.DarkMagneta; break;}
           case 3: { player.Color = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen; break;}
        }
        ListOfPlayers.Add(player); 
     }
  }
  public void StartGame() {
     while(!ListOfPlayers.Any(p => p.TotalScore > 100) {
        StartTurn();
     }
     EndGame();
  }

  public void StartTurn() {
    //each player throw
    foreach(var player in ListOfPlayers) {
       player.Play();
    }
    //calculate each player total score
    ...
    
  }

  public void EndGame() {
     var winner;
  }
}

public class Player {
   private Random = new Random();
   public ConsoleColor Color {get; set;}
   public List<int> Throw = new List<int>();
   public int TotalScope { get; set; } = 0;
   public void Play() {
      Throw.Clear();
      for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        Throw.Add(random.Next(1, 20));
      }
   }
}
```